# Select all items from the top N categories

Tags: sql

can somebody please suggest how to write sql query for MS sql server to select all items from the top N categories from the following scenario?

Table of categories

```
|idCtegory|strName
------------------
|1        |cat 1
|2        |cat 2
|3        |cat 3
|4        |cat 4
```

Table of items

```
|idItem|idCategory
------------------
|1     |1
|2     |1
|3     |3
|4     |2
```

Let's say that I want to select all items from the top 2 categories, therefore I expect to get something like this

```
|idItem|idCategory
------------------
|1     |1
|2     |1
|4     |2
```

I have tried to join the tables, but then I don't know the exact number of items.

Thanks

EDIT:
I just got an idea to join the table of items with the `select top(N) idCategory FROM categories group by idCategory` I hope it will work.

Comment: I'd go for `order by` rather than `group by`, but other than that your solution should work.

Comment: That is what I meant to do, but as I was thinking about groups I wrote it wrong

Comment: Why does your expected output show category 2 rather than 3? 2 is tied with 3. Are you picking arbitrarily when there is a tie?

Comment: I am sorry I have written it wrong. By top N categories I simply meant for example first two in the table of categories. I haven't thought about the ties, because my only problem was how to select top N categoreis (doesn't matter how is the table of categories ordered) therefore the example is simplified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you DO NOT want to keep ties:

```
with tops as
 (select top 2 i.idcategory, count(*) as num_items
    from items i
   group by i.idcategory
   order by num_items desc)
select i.* from items i join tops t on i.idcategory = t.idcategory
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bebb/7/0

If you DO want to keep ties:

```
with tops as
 (select top 2 with ties i.idcategory, count(*) as num_items
    from items i
   group by i.idcategory
   order by num_items desc)
select i.* from items i join tops t on i.idcategory = t.idcategory
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3bebb/8/0  (notice how categories 2 and 3 both come back because they are each tied; they both have exactly one item)

Your expected output indicates you don't care about ties, but I figured I would point it out just in case you actually do.

Answer (score 0):

If by "top category" you mean the ones with the most items, you can use `row_number()` along with aggregation:

```
select iditem, id
from (select idcategory, count(*) as cnt, row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from items
      group by idcategory
     ) c join
     items i
     on c.idcategory = i.idcategory
where segnum <= 1;
```